# Rounding a decimal value with dynamic variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

I need to round a value of a column in table A based on another column in table B in a SQL function.

```
DECLARE @currencyround INT

SELECT @currencyround = ISNULL(currencyround, 2) 
FROM dbo.PRTL_currencySettings
```

When I put value of `@currencyround` directly in the query like the following, it's working fine:

```
SELECT
    CAST(POS.BALANCE AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS DBAmount
FROM 
    dbo.POS_SALES POS
```

When I put value of `@currencyround` like the following, it's showing error:

> Incorrect syntax near '@currencyround'.

```
SELECT
    CAST(POS.BALANCE AS DECIMAL(18, @currencyround)) AS DBAmount
FROM 
    dbo.POS_SALES POS
```

Comment: Maybe you have to create it as a literal string and then [`EXEC` this string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql)?

Comment: Do you want to simply _display_ the result or does the result, with exactly two digits, get used sometime later, perhaps in another query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need specific metadata you could use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @currencyround int;
SELECT @currencyround=ISNULL(currencyround,2) FROM dbo.PRTL_currencySettings;

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
N'select CAST(POS.BALANCE AS DECIMAL(18,<currencyround>)) AS DBAmount
FROM dbo.POS_SALES POS';

SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '<currencyround>', @currencyround);

EXEC(@sql);
```

But personally I would not write such code. I would rather format the number in the application layer.

Answer (score 4):

What do you not understand?  Type definitions don't allow variables.  You could do this with dynamic SQL but that seems like overkill.

If you care about what how the variable is output, use `str()` or `format()` to create the format that you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to *round* the values, then how about this:

```
ROUND(POS.BALANCE, @currencyround)
```